# Making Pagedown work with MarkItUp Editor

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, markdown

I have an MVC3 site that needs to handle user posts. I am trying to use MarkItUp for the text edit because I like its full featured, easy to customize, functionality. However, I am using two markdown libraries for the conversion: [Pagedown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) (client side), and [MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) (server side).

Here's the scripts within my editing view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.markitup.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.markitup.settings.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Markdown.Converter.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Markdown.Sanitizer.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
        $('.editor').markItUp(markdownSettings);
        $('.markdown').live('keyup', function () {
        var md = $('#comment-editor').val();
        var html = converter.makeHtml(md);
        $('#preview').html(html);
    });
    $('.markdown').live('click', function () {
        var md = $('#comment-editor').val();
        var html = converter.makeHtml(md);
        $('#preview').html(html);
    });
});
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
@Html.TextArea("html", "enter your text here", new { id = "comment-editor", @class = "editor" })
<div id="preview" class="markdown"></div>
```

So far so good. The issue/my question is... when I fire this up and begin typing, everything is groovy in that the preview is converting properly as I type, **but *Italic* is not working. Whether i use the _ notation or single * notation, type or click in editor... it is not italicized.**

Is there an issue between the Pagedown converter and the MarkItUp editor? Or did I noob-ishly miss something?

For clarification, here's what the preview DIV looks like (Firebug):

```
<div id="preview" class="markdown">
    <p>stuff you <em>dont</em> see <em>every</em> day.</p>
</div>
```

Note that "dont" is marked with `_` chars, and "every" with `*`.

Comment: What does the HTML look like in the preview? Are the words that are meant to be italic wrapped in any tags at all? Are the markdown characters removed or do they remain in the preview?

Comment: @DavidBrainer-Banker I updated the question for you. From Firebug it seems both the underscore and asterisk chars are wrapping the text in `<em>` as they should.

Comment: Are you using any form of CSS reset script? What styles are applied to the `<em>` elements (you should be able to see this in Firebug too)?

Comment: Yep. I tihnk all user-agent stylesheets have ems italic by default. Most css reset sheets overwrite that.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer Is there a live preview of the site where I can see the behavior for myself? I might be able to point out exactly what is going. However, because you see the `<em>` tags you can rest assured that Markdown is working as intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What [Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241605/matthew-strawbridge) wrote is what I was getting at. It sure sounds to me like you simply have a CSS rule which is preventing the italic styling from displaying as you intend it to. There is nothing at all wrong with your Markdown implementation!

You can fix this without affecting the rest of your site by adding an appropriate CSS rule styling `<em>` elements within `#preview.markdown` as italic.

By the way, the reason that CSS reset scripts remove the styling is this: When you rely on browser defaults to style your content you may be tempted to use tags for their visual effect rather than for their semantic purpose. By doing this you are more likely to encounter issues when browsers interpret the presentation of those elements differently. The resets flip this around and attempt to give you a consistent blank slate within which you can write semantically-valid HTML and then style it to your liking with CSS. You can read more about this in the [introduction to Eric Meyer's reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: I am embarassed. I was so cautious about the javascript libraries working together that I missing something so retarded. i had `em` set in my stylesheet but lost a couple days of source code at one point and did not do a line by line compare.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge - I hope I do not upset, but I'm going to give this one to David as he was the first to respond and it was the reminder to check the live HTML rendered that led to CSS. Thank you for helping as well.

Comment: Thanks for the eyes. I most definitely understand the CSS reset, tabula rasa for browser handling... i'm embarrassed I did not check there. I lost a line somewhere because it was styled before.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer That's fine. David's answer is a good one.

Comment: Not to mention an embarrassing one.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer I wasn't trying to suggest you don't understand those concepts - just filling out the answer a bit for any future users who may wonder into this question.

Comment: @DavidBrainer-Banker No harm done at all, just trying to save a little face after that one. Thanks for the extra pair of eyes.